# JqueryValidation Plugin error messages issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use JQuery Validation plugin on a page where i need to validate a input fields on each row of a table. these input fields doesn't share same name. so i added validation messages to input fields using the addMethod and addClassrules.

```
    $.validator.addMethod("RequiredFields", $.validator.methods.required, "Required Field");
    $.validator.addMethod("EmailValid", $.validator.methods.email, "Invalid Email");
    $.validator.addClassRules("RequiredFieldValidation", {
        RequiredFields: true
    });
    $.validator.addClassRules("EmailValidation", {
        RequiredFields: true,
        EmailValid: true
    });

    $("#Form1").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent("td").parent("tr").find('td:last-child').html() == "") {
                element.parent("td").parent("tr").find('td:last-child').html("*");
                error.appendTo(element.parent("td").parent("tr").find('td:last-child'));
            } else {
                element.parent("td").parent("tr").find('td:last-child').append(" and ");
                error.appendTo(element.parent("td").parent("tr").find('td:last-child'));
            }
        },
        errorClass: "ErrorCell",
        validClass: ""

    });
```

i have added `RequiredFieldValidation` and `EmailValidation` as classes to the input fields.

My HTML looks like below.

```
<pre>
<code>

    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <table id="tbl_Temp">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th class="ErrorCellHeader"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtFName1_Temp" id="txtFName1_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtLName1_Temp" class="RequiredFieldValidation " id="txtLName1_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtEmail1_Temp" class="EmailValidation" id="txtEmail1_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="ErrorMessage"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtFName2_Temp" id="txtFName2_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtLName2_Temp" class="RequiredFieldValidation " id="txtLName2_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="txtEmail2_Temp" class="EmailValidation" id="txtEmail2_Temp" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="ErrorMessage"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</code>
</pre>
```

Everything works fine..except the error messages. i am trying to concatenate messages with "and" but i can't get rid off them when the validation passes.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Demo can be found at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RShpw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Everything works fine..except the error messages. i am trying to
>   concatenate messages with "and" but i can't get rid off them when the
>   validation passes."*

You're using the `errorPlacement` callback to add the `"and"` string between your messages. However, `errorPlacement` is only supposed to be used for *positioning* the `label` elements on the page.  Once the message `label` is created and placed, this callback is of no further use.

> **errorPlacement** (default: Places the error label after the invalid element)
>  Type: Function()
>  **Customize placement of created
>   error labels**. First argument: The created error label as a jQuery
>   object. Second argument: The invalid element as a jQuery object.

Since you need to "toggle" this `"and"` string along with the messages, you'll need to use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.  These *directly* control the toggling of the error messages as required.

Fires when an error message needs to be displayed:

> **highlight** (default: Adds errorClass (see the option) to the element)
>  Type: Function()
>  How to highlight invalid fields.
>   Override to decide which fields and how to highlight.

Fires when an error message needs to be removed:

> **unhighlight** (default: Removes the errorClass)
> Type: Function()
>   **Called to revert changes made by option highlight, same arguments as highlight.**

**See documentation**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/